# Calculating Range and Bearing Using Complex Numbers

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I am trying to build a Range and Bearing calculator using complex numbers. I am using the following equation to find the new coordinates using a range and bearing:

$$(\cos(-r)+\sin(-r)i)(0 + yi)$$

where $r$ is the bearing and $y$ is the range.

I have used $-r$ as I am doing this for a survey application with a North Up convention. This is the same reason that I am using the start point of the rotation at $(0+yi)$ not $(x + 0i)$

I have tested this equation and it seems to work OK. However, how would I be able to re-arrange this equation so as to be able to find the range and bearing if I have the new and old coordinates?

I have drawn a lot of stuff on a sheet of paper but cannot work it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding an image will help with helping you.

Comment: I cannot add an image yet as I do not have enough points. I am still too new to this forum.

Comment: Describe better what is input to your process in basic terms  such as - given a point (x,y), find the coordinates of the point when the distance and direction(bearing?) as reference to (x,y) are given. I am not sure what you mean by bearing.